# Spacing groups of bar in bar plots ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to space groups of bars in my grouped bar plot (image below).
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfPp2.png)

As you can see in the figure above, all the groups of three bars are close. I would like to better segregate theses groups of bars so that it's easier to visualize the data properly.

The code to obtain the plot above is

```
#Load packages - pacman, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse and svglite
pacman::p_load(pacman, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, svglite)

#Create vector using function concatenate c(....) for each "variable"
product_screening <- c("CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", 
           "CH4", "CH4", "CH4", "CH4", "CH4", "CH4", "CH4", "CH4", 
           "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2")
catalyst_screening <- c("15Fe-NT", "15Co-NT", "15Ni-NT", "15Cu-NT", "15Fe-nNT", "15Co-nNT", "15Ni-nNT", "15Cu-nNT", 
              "15Fe-NT", "15Co-NT", "15Ni-NT", "15Cu-NT", "15Fe-nNT", "15Co-nNT", "15Ni-nNT", "15Cu-nNT", 
              "15Fe-NT", "15Co-NT", "15Ni-NT", "15Cu-NT", "15Fe-nNT", "15Co-nNT", "15Ni-nNT", "15Cu-nNT") 
yield_screening <- c(1.69, 1.73, 2.71, 0.57, 1.65, 1.15, 0.489, 0.398,
           0.15, 0.14, 0, 0.140, 0.252, 0.14, 0.149, 0.174,
           1, 0.85, 0.11, 0.65, 0.22, 0.84, 5.42, 0.93)

#Create data frame "screening_data" using function data.frame (vector1, vector2, vector3, ...)
screening_data <- data.frame(product_screening, catalyst_screening, yield_screening)
view(screening_data) #function to visualize the data frame

#Set catalyst as a factor
screening_data$catalyst <- factor(screening_data$catalyst_screening, levels = c("15Fe-NT", "15Fe-nNT", "15Co-NT", "15Co-nNT", "15Ni-NT", "15Ni-nNT", "15Cu-NT", "15Cu-nNT"))

#Code the plot
screening_plot <- ggplot(data = screening_data) + #Stablish screening_plot as a ggplot based on data called screening_data
  geom_col(aes(x = catalyst_screening, y = yield_screening, fill = product_screening), position = position_dodge(1), width = .75) + #Creates column plot
  theme_bw() + #Parameters for plot aesthetics
  theme(axis.text = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 15, color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 16, margin = margin(t = 15)),
        axis.title.y = element_text( family = "Arial", size = 16, margin = margin(r = 15)),axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey85"),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "grey95"),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.20, units = "cm"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.key.width = unit(0.6, unit = "cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.6, unit = "cm"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 13.5),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"),
        legend.text.align = unit(0.05, unit = "cm")) +
  labs(y ="Gas Evolution (µmol.g"^-1~")", x = "Catalyst") + #Set axes labels
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,6)) + #Limit the size of the plot
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Methane", "Carbon Monoxide", "Hydrogen"), #Set legend labels
                    values = c(CO = "palegreen3" ,CH4 = "sandybrown",H2 = "cadetblue")) + #Set legend and bar colors
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1, accuracy = 1), #Set parameters for the scales
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0)),
                     n.breaks = 5)
#Plot the plot
screening_plot
```

I tried changing the width in geom_col, but it doesn't affect exactly what I want, it just makes the bars thinner or thicker.

I don't want to evenly space all the bars, I want to space them in groups of three, the three products obtained (CO, CH4 and H2)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have set `width=1` in `position_dodge()`. Using a `width<1` will add some space between your groups:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = screening_data) +
  geom_col(aes(x = catalyst_screening, y = yield_screening, fill = product_screening),
    position = position_dodge(.8), width = .75
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 15, color = "black"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 16, margin = margin(t = 15)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 16, margin = margin(r = 15)), axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey85"),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "grey95"),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0.20, units = "cm"),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.key.width = unit(0.6, unit = "cm"),
    legend.key.height = unit(0.6, unit = "cm"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 13.5),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.text.align = unit(0.05, unit = "cm")
  ) +
  labs(y = "Gas Evolution (µmol.g"^-1 ~ ")", x = "Catalyst") + # Set axes labels
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 6)) + # Limit the size of the plot
  scale_fill_manual(
    labels = c("Methane", "Carbon Monoxide", "Hydrogen"), # Set legend labels
    values = c(CO = "palegreen3", CH4 = "sandybrown", H2 = "cadetblue")
  ) + # Set legend and bar colors
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1, accuracy = 1), # Set parameters for the scales
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0)),
    n.breaks = 5
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, easy. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: :D Just to clarify. With the `width` argument of `position_dodge`you set the width or the amount by which the bars get dodged or shifted from the center and determines the amount of padding between the groups. The width argument sets (as you already figured out) the width of the bars.